# Difference between bear and bear with

Tags: usage

Which one of the two words either **bear** or **bear with** should be used in the following sentence?

> If you are living near a market place you should be ready to ________ the disturbances caused by traffic.

I think it should be **bear** because **bear with** means **to ask somebody to be patient with you while you finish doing something**. But there is no such request in the above sentence.

But many websites say it should be **bear with**

Which one is correct, kindly share your views.

Comment: Which websites specifically? I don't think I've ever heard _bear with_ outside of the set expression "bear with me" (or trivial variants like "He asked me to bear with him," etc.).

Comment: Please bear with me while I bare my teeth to help bear the pain from this bear bite!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=if+you+are+living+near+main+market+place+you+should+be+ready+to+wear+the+disturbances+caused+by+traffic&oq=if&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i59j69i60.1207j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The website at the top of those search results is simply wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"Bear with" seems to be the answer, although it is more idiomatic to say you are bearing with the *source* of a problem rather than the problem itself. For example "bear with **us** through these disturbances".

It cannot be "bear", because that means *to carry*, especially a responsibility, and the sentence would not make sense because it would mean you were asking someone to take responsibility for the disturbances, not tolerate them.

Even with the "correct" answer, it isn't quite idiomatic for another reason - we only tend to use "bear with" when speaking about *temporary* disturbances, not permanent situations. For a permanent situation that required patient we would either ask someone to "tolerate" it, or "put up with" it.

Comment: @Astalbee Bear can also mean tolerate